# innerHTML in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am now spending hours on one thing.
innerHTML changes div or

javascript code:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Template -->
<div id="faqask" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="margin-top:20%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Uzdot Jautājumu</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="demo" >trlololo</p>
                <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
                <select name="faqcategory" id='inputSelect' class="form-control form-group-margin input-lg">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>-Izvēlies-</option>
                    <option value="visparigie" />Vispārīgie
                    <option value="serveris"/>Serveris
                    <option value="pakalpojumi"/>Pakalpojumi
                </select>
                <textarea placeholder="Tavs Jautājums" class="form-control form-group-margin input-lg" rows="6"></textarea>
                <div class="clearfix"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-flat btn-primary" onclick="faqsend()">Iesūtīt jautājumu</button></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- / .modal-content -->
    </div><!-- / .modal-dialog -->

</div>
<!-- / Template -->
```

I tested, if i put trlololo

outside of MODAL trololo change to Hello World, if i put it inside nothing happens.

But I really want it to work, because i want to send error to modal, so when button is pressed user get results to MODAL. But can`t get it to change. Outside it dose.

Comment: "inside" mean where exactly ?

Comment: Bootstrap Modal, the modal code. If the  <p id="demo" >trlololo</p> is anywhere outside modal code that i gave, it changes to Hello World. But if it`s inside modal code, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to work on jsfiddle. However, I had to change when the javascript runs to inside the body, likely after the page has loaded. You can, however, switch to jQuery since Bootstrap requires it to handle your clicking of the button for you.

```js
$('#yourButtonID').click(function() {

  $('#demo').html('Hello World!');

});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/vy3b34ye/)

I added a button to show the modal.

If you don't want to change your code then I would suggest adding `myFunction()` to the end of the page just before the end of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: okey, so, i will debug everything around that code, thank you!

Comment: I found the problem. Its the way i open the model, if i open it manually like you did it works, but i opened straight from bottom just by id="faqask-btn" and it automaticly opens modal with the same ID. Thank You :)